# CakePHP3.2: I can't delete dependent associated

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I should make a big mistake as I already done this several times, but I really don't understand why deleting associated only partially works:

My entities are declared like that:

```
class SitemessagesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('sitemessages');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('SitemessageTitles', [
            'dependent' => true,
        ]);

    }
}

class SitemessageTitlesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('sitemessage_titles');
        $this->displayField('title');

        $this->belongsTo('Sitemessages');

        $this->hasOne('SitemessageTexts', [
            'dependent' => true,
        ]);

        $this->hasOne('SitemessageImages', [
            'dependent' => true,
        ]);

    }
}

class SitemessageTextsTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('sitemessage_texts');
        $this->displayField('text');

        $this->belongsTo('SitemessageTitles');

    }
}

class SitemessageImagesTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('sitemessage_images');
        $this->displayField('image');

        $this->belongsTo('SitemessageTitles');

    }
}
```

So I try to delete a Sitemessages entity like that:

```
    $sitemessage = $this->Sitemessages->get($sitemessage_id);

    $this->Sitemessages->delete($sitemessage);
```

Then `Sitemessages` and first level `SitemessageTitles` entites are deleted but not the second level `SitemessageTexts` nor `SitemessageImages` ones.

I don't understand as the doc says:

> When deleting entities, associated data can also be deleted. If your HasOne and HasMany associations are configured as dependent, delete operations **will ‘cascade’** to those entities as well.

Any idea?

Regards,

Comment: Start with checking whether you are operating with the expected table objects: `debug(get_class($this->Sitemessages->SitemessageTitles->target()))`

Comment: @ndm it gives me `'App\Model\Table\SitemessageTitlesTable'`. I didn't really understand what [target](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Association.html#_target) is supposed to tell me. I tried on other models and I get the error  'unknown method target'.

Comment: @ndm, I'm always in the fog about this problem. I tried to not using camelCase naimg, even if that shouldn't be the cause of the problem, i.e. `Sitemessagetitles` instead of `SitemessageTitles` and check again every association declaration, I always have the same problem. Do you have any other advise to check what's wrong please?

Comment: @ndm what I don't understand is why I can add or edit `sitemessage` correctly with its associated and I just cannot fully delete it?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that [**the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/deleting-data.html#cascading-deletes) are a little unclear about the `dependent` option, as it will only affect the first level association. If you want to have fully cascading deletes, you need to enable the `cascadeCallbacks` option too.

Comment: you are right, I didn't put `cascadeCallbacks` at the top level. It's the reason why it didn't work. But that point is very very not clear and why to use `dependent` for the first level and `cascadeCallbacks` for the subsequent levels ??

Comment: @2ndGAB Well, you'll have to ask the CakePHP devs why they've chosen/kept this wording. The technical side of the story is, that `dependent` will use `Table::deleteAll()`, which deletes the associated records in a single query, and `cascadeCallbacks` uses `Table::delete()` on every single associated entity, where in turn possible dependent associations will be deleted too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm discussing about it with MarkStory.

Comment: @ndm describes the behaviou as it should be. However, even with cascadeCallbacks in place, it doesn't work for me.